# cocos2d-x: JPG image becomes dark

Tags: cocos2d-x

I use JPG image as background image in my game to reduce size.
It's working fine in >iOS 5. But in iOS 4.3.3 it become dark.
It will be great if anyone can explain exactly why this problem can be occurred and how it can be resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: I remember an issue with darkening JPG files. You might want to search for that in the cocos2d forum. Btw, JPG may decrease size but they also tremendously increase loading times. Usually you don't want that tradeoff, not even to save space. See the "Image Formats Loading Times" section in this article: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/depth-ios-cocos2d-performance-analysis-test-project/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this problem can be found [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/17929?r=17955). At the same time another thing we should keep in mind, "JPG formate takes much longer times to load than PNG formate"